# How to improve what I did to build and edit on Fortnite

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

I have some issues :

- If I loop on MB4 to build floor then when I press MB5 at the same time it doesn't build both. The same in the opposite way. That's why no loop on MB4. Can I loop both and stairs and roof too without this issue?
- My increase dpi and decrease dpi have issues too when I press release quickly several buttons. I still stuck in height dpi which gets it hard to aim. Why does it do that?
- MoveMouseRelative moves very fast but I noticed that when I make my mouse move up then right it often gets a shortcut. So I miss some squares when I edit. How can that be fixed?
- The Fortress loop works pretty good (fast and right) but sometimes with no reason a wall is not build or something else goes wrong! Why?

```
    Script Lua pour Fortnite sur logitech gaming software par ALWD
     MurLua est une macro simple pour construire un mur
     Solua est une macro simple pour construire un sol
     ToitSolua est une macro simple pour construire un sol et un toit
     Piège est une macro simple pour construire un piège
     PlusReso est une macro simple pour augmenter le DPI à 3000 dans mon cas
     MoinsReso est une macro simple pour baisser le DPI à 800 (par default) dans mon cas
    
    ----------------
     Lua script for fortnite on Logitech gaming software by ALWD
     MurLua is a simple wall build macro
     Solua is a simple stair build macro
     ToitSolua is a simple stair and roof build macro
     Piège is a simple trap build macro
     PlusReso macro increase DPI to 3000 in my case
     MoinsReso macro decrease DPI to default 800 in my case
        
    ----------------
    -- FastSleep definition (Thanks to Egor Skriptunoff)
    
       local function busyloop(final_ctr)
          final_ctr = final_ctr - final_ctr%1
          local ctr, prev_ms, ms0, ctr0 = 0
          while ctr ~= final_ctr do
             local ms = GetRunningTime()
             if prev_ms and ms ~= prev_ms then
                if not ms0 then
                   ms0, ctr0 = ms, ctr
                elseif final_ctr < 0 and ms - ms0 > 500 then
                   return (ctr - ctr0) / (ms - ms0)
                end
             end
             prev_ms = ms
             ctr = ctr + 1
          end
       end
       local coefficient = busyloop(-1)
       function FastSleep(ms)
          return busyloop(ms * coefficient)
       end
       
    ----------------
    
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
      OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    
    ----------------
    --Double function bouton du milieu de la souris - Middle mouse button double function
    ----------------
    
                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        PressAndReleaseKey(3) -- Arme 3 - Weapon slot 3
                        end
                    end
    
                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                        repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
                        FastSleep(12)
                        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                        end
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
                        PressAndReleaseKey(5) -- Arme 5 - Weapon slot 5
                        end
                    end
    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 4 sol ou sol et toit - MB4 floor or floor and roof
    ----------------
    
                    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
                      PlayMacro("PlusReso")
    
                      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
    
                      end
    
                      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7)
                        FastSleep(1)
                        -- Petite Boucle - Little Loop
                        for i=1, 20 do
                        for j=1, 5 do
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit - Roof
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
                        end
                        for j=1, 5 do
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
                        end
                        end
    
                      end
    
                      elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 4) then
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
                        ReleaseKey("F6")
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                        end
    
                    end
    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 5 mur ou sol et mur - MB5 wall or wall and floor
    ----------------
    
                    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
                        PlayMacro("PlusReso")
    
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                        repeat
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                        FastSleep(1)
    
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mode construction Mur
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                        FastSleep(1)
                        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
                        ReleaseKey("F6")
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        end
    
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                        repeat
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F1")-- Mode construction Mur
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                        FastSleep(1)
                        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                        ReleaseKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                        end
                        end
                    end
                    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 6 éscalier ou escalier, sol et toit - MB6 stair or stair, floor and roof
    ----------------
    
                    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then
    
                      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F3")-- Escalier
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                        FastSleep(1)
                      end
    
                      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        FastSleep(1)
                        for i=1, 10 do
                        for j=1, 5 do
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F3")-- Escalier
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
                        end
                        for j=1, 5 do
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F4")-- Toit
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
                        end
                        for j=1, 5 do
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F2")-- Sol - Floor
                           FastSleep(1)
                        PressKey("F6")-- Construire - Place Building
                           FastSleep(1)
                        end
                        end
                      end
    
    
                      elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6) then
                        ReleaseKey("F6")
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                        PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                        end
                    end
    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 9 piège ou changer matériaux - MB9 Trap or change material
    ----------------
    
                    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9) then
                      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        PlayMacro("Piège")
                      end
    
                      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        FastSleep(1)
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7)-- Mode construction
                                            FastSleep(100)
                        PressAndReleaseKey(10) --Modifier Materiaux construction
                                            FastSleep(1)
                          end
    
                          elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 9) then
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        end
    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 8 edit en rond ou du haut vers le bas mur ou escalier - MB8 round edit or up and down stair and wall             
    ----------------
    -- CapsLock OFF
    -- Edit en rond - Round edit
    
      if not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
            if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
    
                        PressAndReleaseKey("BackSpace")-- Edit
                        FastSleep(5)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("T")-- Reset Edit
    
                if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
    
                        --Regarder - Look
                            for i = 0, 20 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
    
                        -- Dessiner Edit - Draw Edit
                            PressKey(13)-- Select Edit
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 4 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 4 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (127,0) -- droite - right
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (-127,0) -- gauche- left
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (-127,0) -- gauche - left
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,127) -- bas - down
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 6 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(1)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-127) -- haut - up
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
    
                            for i = 0, 5 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (127,0) -- droite- right
                           FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           FastSleep(5)
                end
    
    -- Edit de haut en bas - Up and down edit
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
                        -- Dessiner Edit
                            FastSleep(10)
                            PressKey(13)-- Select Edit
                            FastSleep(10)
    
                            for i = 0, 60 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,50) -- bas - down
                            FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                            FastSleep(10)
    
                            for i = 0, 30 do
                            MoveMouseRelative (0,-98) -- haut - up
                            FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                            FastSleep(10)
                end
            end
    
      if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 8 then
    
                        FastSleep(1)
                        ReleaseKey(13)-- Select Edit
                        FastSleep(1)
    
                        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
                        PlayMacro("MoinsReso")
                        PressAndReleaseKey("F1")
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
                        end
        end
      end
    
    ----------------
    -- Boutton 8 Construire une forteresse (4x murs, 2x sols et un toit) - Build a fortress (4x walls, 2x floor and a roof)
    ----------------
    -- CapsLock ON
    
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
            if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
    
                        Sleep(10)
    
                        PlayMacro("Solua")--1 Sol sans Pose !!! Floor not posed !!!
                        Sleep(10)
    
                        -- Regarder en Bas - Look Down
                            for i = 0, 25 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,127)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           Sleep(50)-- ne pas modifier - Don't change
    
                        PlayMacro("Solua")--1 Sol Bas Pose - Floor down posed
                        Sleep(80)-- ne pas modifier - Don't change
    
                        PlayMacro("MurLua")--1 Mur Face sans Pose !!! Wall not posed !!!
    
                        -- Regarder devant - Look ahead
                            for i = 0, 25 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,-127)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                           Sleep(50)-- ne pas modifier
    
                        PlayMacro("MurLua")--1 Mur Face Pose - Wall ahead posed
    
                        -- Regarder droite - Look right
                            for i = 0, 25 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(127,0)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                        Sleep(20)
    
                        PlayMacro("MurLua")--2 Mur Droite Pose - Wall Right posed
    
                        -- Regarder derriere - Look behind
                            for i = 0, 25 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(127,0)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                        Sleep(50)-- ne pas modifier - Don't change
    
                        PlayMacro("MurLua")--3 Mur Arriere Pose - Wall behind posed
    
                        -- Regarder gauche
                            for i = 0, 24 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(127,0)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                        Sleep(80)-- ne pas modifier - Don't change
    
                        PlayMacro("MurLua")--5 Mur Gauche Pose - Wall left posed
                        Sleep(20)
    
                        -- Regarder devant - Look ahead
                            for i = 0, 24 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(127,0)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
                        Sleep(20)
    
                        -- Regarder en haut - Look up
                            for i = 0, 25 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,-127)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
    
                        Sleep(20)
    
                        PlayMacro("ToitSolua")-- Toit et Sol en haut Pose - Floor and roof up posed
    
                        Sleep(150)-- ne pas modifier - Don't change (Si moins pose Toit en bas - if less floor n roof posed down)
    
                        -- Regarder devant - Look ahead
                            for i = 0, 24 do
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,127)
                        FastSleep(0.5)
                            end
    
      end
    
      if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 8 then
                        PressAndReleaseKey("capslock")
                        PressAndReleaseKey(7) -- Alterner les raccourcis - Switch Quickbar
      end
      end
    
    
    end
```

Comment: the button you clicked to create this post is labeled "Ask Question". Unfortunately you did not ask anything. please do not ask for general guidance or tips. Ask a specific question and provide a [mcve]. please read [ask] and take the [tour]. then improve your post

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Comment: Ok thanks Piglet. My code works pretty good but i have some issues in game. So your saying I should take only pieces of my code and asking for help on each issue ? Or should I post all my questions in this "topic"?  My first  question on overflow so it's a little bit hard to understand how it works.

Comment: I added some questions. Hope this is ok now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: create one post per question. post only the relevant code and explain what you expect the code to do and how it behaves instead. you should also present some own ideas and debuggin attempts.